# Problem with subdivision: keeping a smooth curve between multiple separate panels

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

I have a mesh that consists of some adjacent panels. I'm using the subdivision modifier to get everything to look smooth. And although my base mesh looks all lined up well, I can't seem to get the panels to flow along a smooth curve at the seams. I do understand why this happens, but I'm wondering if there are some workflows that can prevent this.
[image: without subdiv]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to shrink wrap it all on a base mesh and although it fixes the curvature problem, the gaps remain at the T-shaped joint areas.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The modifier has no reason to round the panels as they are discontinued